# Is retain attribute for UIView properties with ARC required?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Before ARC, you would declare properties in your .h file as:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIView *someUIView;
```

With ARC, do I still need to use `retain` or can I just write this?

```
@property (nonatomic) UIView *someUIView;
```

Answer (score 2):

In LLVM 3.1 and later, you can do either, because they're the same.  Under ARC, `strong` (which is the same as `retain`) is the default, if not specified, for retainable object pointers.

Quoting from the [LLVM ARC doc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html):

> A property of retainable object pointer type which is synthesized
>   without a source of ownership has the ownership of its associated
>   instance variable, if it already exists; otherwise, [beginning Apple
>   3.1, LLVM 3.1] its ownership is implicitly strong. Prior to this revision, it was ill-formed to synthesize such a property.

I usually find myself typing "strong" anyway, I think because since `assign` was previously the default, it scares me for just a split second every time I see a retainable object property with no ownership specified.

Answer (score 1):

The `strong` keyword has been advertised on place of `retain`, but they are really the same thing. So you can use `strong` or `retain`.

Your view WILL need to be retained by at least one object. If your view is already being retained by another object, you could make it an `assign` (aka weak) property. Otherwise you could keep the `retain` or `strong` keyword.